# Logging in into shell as sudo user and executing shell through java

Tags: java, shell, runtime, exec, sudo

i have a shell file that needs to be executed through java program. But, the problem is the shell file is n't getting executed because usually we run shell files through command line after executing the sudo command which in turn asks for password.Is there any possibility that i can execute the shell using Runtime.exec("ksh path-to-shell-file") by-passing the sudo command.

Answer (score 0):

You can write commands to the outStream of the process from Runtime.exec();

Get the outStream, write a command to it, and then write "\r\n" to it to execute.

So basically treat the process as a console, and write commands to it like to normal console. Obviously you can also get the in and err streams